# Show Virtualbox Virtual Terminals in Different Windows

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-terminal

We can switch between virtual terminals in Virtualbox with CTRL+ALT+FX.

Is there a way to display these in different windows, so we can see them side by side?

Comment: Cn you open multiple VB instances and show a different terminal in each? I have another app I wish I could run in a multi window config, but this is a very edge use case and simply not supported with most software.

Comment: Unfortunately once a VM is running, VB replaces the "Start" option for the VM with "Show", which just goes to the running VM. Opening another VB window also only gives this option. Do you mean setting up a second installation of VB?

Comment: Ok, then no. You're basically asking how you can have a single VM in two different windows. This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Each VM can only show in a single VB window.

While you can create multi user systems and use remote desktop methods to access these, each view will be a distinct session, and it won't be happening within the VB interface.